# Swapping each word in a string into a certain order

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a string of text from one text box and put it into the next text box inverted but readable like this. "Help please" and in the next box when I click the button it should say "please Help". I have been trying everything that I can think of. Sorry very new to this. Ill attach the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string converttext = txtInputBox.Text;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(converttext.Length);
    for (int i = converttext.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        sb.Append(converttext[i]);
    }
    string reversed = sb.ToString();

    txtOutputBox.Text = reversed;
}
```

Comment: What result DO you get?

Comment: I'm getting "esaelp pleH" from "Help please"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txtOutputBox.Text = String.Join(" ", txtInputBox.Text.Split().Reverse());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split the string on space and then reverse the result and pass it to `string.Join` like:

```
string str = "Help please";
string newStr = string.Join(" ", str.Split().Reverse());
```

Comment: I think separator should be a string :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, yup just fixed that :)

Comment: Note that these are very simple approaches. Words might be separated by other characters as well(like `,;()[]/.` etc). It will also replace tabs or line-breaks with an empty space.